# Fundamental group of a covering space

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I understand the correspondence between the subgroups of a fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$ and the covering spaces of $X$.

However, I do not understand what is implied about the fundamental groups of those covering spaces. Are they the associated subgroups of $X$?

In other words, if subgroup $A\subset \pi_1(X)$ is associated with a covering space $Y$, is it true that $\pi_1(Y)=A$? (Or is it $\pi(X)/A$? Or is it not determined by $\pi(X)$ at all?)

Comment: Yes, that's right. (Incidentally, if you didn't know this, then in fact you did not understand the correspondence between subgroups of the fundamental group and covering spaces.)